# How to deploy Play! framework app to Openshift v3

Tags: java, playframework, openshift

Perhaps I pop this question to early as Openshift v3 is still in preview, nevertheless there might be a solution to my problem that I don't see :).

I'm taking my first steps in building a java Play framework app and chose Openshift as my hosting platform. I just was able to get my app + mysql db working on Openshift v2 as they released v3 preview and got notice v2 will eventually disappear.
In the new images/templates there is still no Java Play version showing and no 'do it yourself cartridge' way.

Any hints or 'tutorial' links are much appreciated :).

Thanks and kind regards!
Erik

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here.

**SBT Native Packager**

First option would be using the SBT Native Packager SBT builder to create your Docker images (either manually or using something like Jenkins). Out of the box you should be able to run `sbt docker:publishLocal` and get a local docker image which you can then push to a Docker repo. You can then launch it in openshift with `oc new-app <docker repo>/<docker image>:<image version>`.

Down side to this is that you aren't really taking advantage of OpenShift fully since your images are being built elsewhere. But it might fit well with your current development flow.

Upside is that your docker images will be quite small. SBT does a good job of packaging up all the dependencies.

**Source to Image**

Second option would be to create your own [source to image](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) builder that knows how to build sbt/play projects. This is the path my team has taken. You can take a look at [our sbt builder](https://github.com/OutThereLabs/s2i-scala) for reference but its still beta quality at best.

Downside to this process is that all your source is included in the image so its a big larger. Also no one supports this builder so if you have bugs you are on your own.

Upside is that OpenShift will build your images and you will see your build status inside the OpenShift web console.

**Notes**

With OpenShift Origin 1.3.0 you will also get access to the Jenkins pipeline. This can make either of the two above scenarios easier. You end up with a cool web interface that looks like this:

[image: OpenShift Build Pipeline Screenshot]

Hopefully RedHat will support sbt natively at some point but for now one of these two flows should work for you.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for your reply. Just tried installing docker in my w10 vm and that doesn't work. Will try the source to image approach next. As I am completely new to this, could you give me a quick step by step way of getting the source code at openshift (online); I suppose there has to be a way through git? Thanks!

Comment: To get started you want to install the binary from https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/tag/v1.3.0 and then run `oc cluster up`. You shouldn't need any source code.

Comment: The `oc cluster up` command also seems to need docker installed locally (which I am unable to do in my VM environment)? I'm getting this output:
`$ oc cluster up
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... FAIL
   Error: cannot communicate with Docker`
I thought my code could be 'dockerized' by Openshift itself, just by pushing my code to a git repository that has a webhook to an Openshift project? But as I understand now, I think I need to get a basic docker image at Openshift to which I then can push code?

Comment: Correct, you need to set up OpenShift first. There are instructions here: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md

Comment: Hi, I have finally gotten as far as creating my own docker image. I needed a fresh vm to get docker toolbox installed and then I had been playing with making my own dockerfile and ended up with a 2.3GB size image ... :-O. I then tried sbt native packager (activator docker:publishLocal) and ended up with a 333MB image, yipee.
I got again an openshift online account and today was able to start a new project from my image which I uploaded to docker hub.
Result: pod won't start. Do I need extra setup for a native packaged image to run?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone looking for an answer to my own question, here is how I got a Play app running on Openshift (own installation).
First of all, a big thank you @PatrickTescher. His answer pointed me in the right direction.

I did not yet succeed in getting a docker build by activator to work in Openshift (guessing it has to do with running under root), but I have gotten to the point where I have a Source to Image build running on my own Openshift Cluster. This approach is not yet possible with the online developer preview of Openshift. By all the reading I have done so far, I agree with Patrick to say this is the best approach.

By diving into the following links, you should get up and running:

- Installing docker on a Windows vm: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/overview/
- Installing your own Openshift Cluster: https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/docs/cluster_up_down.md#windows-with-docker-toolbox (in addition: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/11277)
- Get a s2i image up and running: https://github.com/redhat-cop/containers-quickstarts/tree/master/s2i-play

In the last link you can change registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7.2 by registry.centos.org/centos/centos:latest (rhel needs certification, centos is the free community equivalent)